# How can I set "create a single schema for each s3 path" in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I want to create a crawler resource from CFN (Cloudformation).
Here is my code:

```
Type: AWS::Glue::Crawler
    Properties: 
      Name: !Ref GlueCrawlerName
      Role: !GetAtt crawlerRole.Arn
      Description: AWS Glue crawler to crawl DLG data
      DatabaseName: !Ref GlueDatabaseName
      Targets:
        S3Targets:
          - Path: 
              !Join
              - ''
              - - 's3://'
                - !Ref s3bucket
                - '/'
                - !Ref GlueTableName
      SchemaChangePolicy:
        UpdateBehavior: UPDATE_IN_DATABASE
        DeleteBehavior: DEPRECATE_IN_DATABASE
      Schedule:
        ScheduleExpression: cron(0 1 * * ? 2019)
```

Everything is alright as expected, only 'Create a single schema for each S3 path' is false. Which property is for this to set to true?

Comment: Please, try to be more specific and explain exactly what you are trying to achieve and what your current setup looks like. The question is completely unanswerable as it stands right now.

Comment: Can you check now ? @MatusDubrava

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need one table per subfolder or only one table at the root level of the s3 path?

for single root level table, append following in your CFN:

```
Configuration: "{\"Version\":1.0,\"Grouping\":{\"TableGroupingPolicy\":\"CombineCompatibleSchemas\"}}"
```

Comment: only one table at the root.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it will be helpful. As per AWS documentation:

> Set the Configuration field with a string representation of the
>   following JSON object in the crawler API:

```
{
   "Version": 1.0,
   "Grouping": {
      "TableGroupingPolicy": "CombineCompatibleSchemas" }
}
```

Comment: Can i achieve the same using cloud formation only?